# Prove that $100n \leq 2^n$, for every integer $n \geq 10$

Tags: inequality, induction

I have started this proof with the base case $n = 10$. In this case, it's true because $1000 < 1024$.

Next I assume that $n \geq 11$ and that $100(n-1) \leq {2}^{n-1}$. As the right side is already bigger, we can multiply it by 2 without changing the inequality, hence we have that $100(n-1) \leq 2^n$.
But I am currently stuck in this part. How would I proceed from here?
I know I need to show that $100n \leq 2^n$.

Comment: For the induction step we assume that for some $k$ we have $100k\le 2^k $ then consider

$$100(k+1)=100k+100\le 2^k+100\le 2^k+2^k=2\;2^k=2^{k+1}$$

which holds for $k\ge 10$.

Comment: That makes sense and is easier, thank you! Of curiosity, if I would like to do it from n - 1 to n instead? Is there some way to do it?

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24100n%5Cle%202%5En%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24n%5Cge%2010%24&p=1), there are quite a few very similar questions here, e.g., [How can I prove that eventually one function will overtake another, and find when?](/q/2967615), [Prove by minimum counterexample that $2^n>10n$ for $n>5$](/q/574291), [Prove via mathematical induction that $4n < 2^n$ for all $ n≥5$.](/q/131036), etc.

Comment: @VictorFeitosa Yes of course, the argument is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have shown $P(n)$ to be true for your base case, there is no need to perform any further instantiation. Instead you state the induction hypothesis: $P(n)$ is true for some $n=k$ in the domain. Then perform the induction step and proceed normally. Let $n=k+1$; then $100(k+1) = 100k+100$. By the induction hypothesis, $100k \le 2^k$, which means that $100k+100 \le 2^k+100$. $100 \le 2^k$, therefore $100k+100 \le 2^k+2^k = 2×2^k = 2^{k+1}$. QED.